# how do i count the amount of rows under a username?

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a forum and on the homepage I want to make some kind of a leaderboard where you can see the top 10 posters + and how much they have posted. I want to only get those users out of the database. Ill add a picture of my database. Please let me know.

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79yLM.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome, stackoverflow is not a coding service, did you write code for you project? If yes please post it and we can help you

Comment: _"I have no idea how i could achieve this."_ is a very poor basis for a Stack Overflow question. You are expected to present a specific programming issue you're having, not to just ask someone else to do the whole thing for you. I'd recommend reading [ask] and editing your question accordingly.

Comment: okay sorry. it wont happen again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean, but if you mean the database query, it can be something like this:

```
SELECT username, 
       COUNT(*) AS total_post 
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY username 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Please avoid answering poorly defined questions that show no effort. By answering them, we encourage low quality posts on Stack Overflow, which is not the site's goal.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your table name posts. You can replace it by your table name.

`SELECT COUNT(post) as total_post, username FROM posts GROUP BY username;`

It will return something like

```
total_post   username 

   5         username
```

Comment: Please avoid answering poorly defined questions that show no effort. By answering them, we encourage low quality posts on Stack Overflow, which is not the site's goal.